# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in javafx program

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently trying to code a simple MediaPlayer to explore javafx.
(beginner here)
I want to open a mp3 file and simply play it but when i launch it there is an exception ive never seen.

Heres the code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Media pick = new Media("file:///" + System.getProperty("Benutzer.dir").replace('\\', '/') + "/" + "oof.mp3");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);

    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

    Group root = new Group(mediaView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

    primaryStage.setTitle("MediaPlayerTest");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    player.play();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

And the exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at soundEdit.start(soundEdit.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
```

Already tried to find a solution but cant really find anything.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: is the path you use in new Media(...) correct?

Comment: `System.getProperty("Benutzer.dir")` returns `null`.

Comment: @fabian This question can't be considered a duplicate for the provided link, the problem is that he's incorrectly accessing the resources for his application, also he's not asking what's a null pointer exception he's asking how to solve the problem of accessing resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the stack of error you will notice that the error is caused by a null pointer exception at line 13 of the code can you kindly highlight that line, not sure which one.

Also when getting resources it's best to use the `getClass().getResourcesAsStream()` or `getClass().getResource()` methods.

Comment: Line 13 of the code is:

Media pick = new Media("file:///" + System.getProperty("Benutzer.dir").replace('\\', '/') + "/" + "oof.mp3");

Comment: Can you try printing the result of System.getProperty("Benutzer.dir")

Comment: Says null when i print it

Comment: That's the problem you try to use . replace () on a null value as such the null pointer exception

Comment: So where should i put the mp3 then and how can i use it in the project?

Comment: Put the MP3 file under the src file and use the getClass().getResource() method, it returns the URL of the file and I think there is a .getFile() method under it

Comment: The get resource method takes the path to the file and always start with / which will refrence the src folder